# Get complete data from redux persist store

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to Get complete data from redux persist store to take backup of store and store in my drive. Kindly help me to get the complete values in my store

I have tried by using store.getstate(). Can anyone guide my to get it

Answer (score 1):

Use `subscribe` to add a state change listener, and put your logic in it.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  var state = store.getState();
  // Your logic
});
```

Comment: My need is no to know store change... i need all vales in store... not store change listner... i need the complete vale set

Comment: The listener gives you the state change event, the `store.getState()` gives you the state tree.